# To what extent may Jews use natural resources

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, natural-phenomenon, environment, property

The [tragedy of the commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons) is a concept that if you have a (generally natural) finite resource with everyone having access to it, it will eventually get overused. My question is, to what extent are Jews prohibited from using Hefker natural resources due to this? This could have implications for example for industrial fish farms.

Comment: I don't know of a specific source for this, but presumably it would fall under the Rabbis' jurisdiction of setting the proper terms of trade. See the second chapter of Bava Basra.